# What is the reason for "Permission Denied" error after an 'yarn add'?

Tags: git, github

Brand new react-native project, tried to run `npm install react-native-firebase/app` and `yarn add react-native-firebase/app` from inside the project directory and this was the result:

```
Jamess-MacBook-Pro:Redux_ReactNav vorousjames$ yarn add react-native-firebase/app
yarn add v1.5.1
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/react-native-firebase/app.git
Directory: /Users/vorousjames/Desktop/Development/Redux_ReactNav/Redux_ReactNav
Output:
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.114.3' to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/vorousjames/Desktop/Development/Redux_ReactNav/Redux_ReactNav/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

After looking into the issue, I never set generated any public keys or anything like that on my machine or with github, anyone know how to successfully install an npm project with this error?

Comment: The error is raised by `git ls-remote`. To generate and add ssh keys, see https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.16/user/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent.

Answer (score 0):

Beside making sure your public SSH key is registered to your account (`ssh -Tv git@github.com`), you need to make sure the repository app does exist.

I don't see an "app" repository in https://github.com/react-native-firebase

It might be private (in which case, you should be a member of the [React Native Firebase](https://github.com/orgs/react-native-firebase/people) organization), but if it does not exists, you will get that error message.